# Kotlin compiler error -d invalid argument

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am getting an error when I go to compile the `kotlin` cmd file for Windows, using their *Hello, World!* one, but I had to modify part of the compile command to get the `-target` part to be valid. I am not sure how to fix the `invaled -d` argument that they show to use.

The text editor is [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code).

Compiler: Kotlin-native-windows-1.4.32.zip from [JetBrains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains)' GitHub account - https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.4.32

My compiler command is `kotlinc.bat helloworld.kt -target mingw_x64 -d "hello world/hello world.jar"`

Output:

```
error: invalid argument: -d
info: use -help for more information
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Kotlin/Native compiler, and it supports a different set of command-line arguments.

The solution is to download the Kotlin/JVM compiler from the archive named `kotlin-compiler-1.4.32.zip`.
Since Kotlin 1.5-M1, the Native compiler will show a clarifying warning for this case: *[Native / CLI: provide a way to show difference between Jvm and Native compilers](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43874)*.